# How to validate 12-Hour Time with regex (regular Expression)

Tags: javascript, php, regex

I want to validate a 12-Hours time format like (01:05 PM) in PHP, Javascript and HTML.

I tried this:

```
((([1-9])|(1[0-2])):([0-5])(0|5)\s(A|P)M)
```

But I don't know why it doesn't work.

Comment: @Gopal—are you sure that will match hours with a leading zero (per the OP)?

Comment: Is this a JS problem, or a PHP problem? What have you tried to resolve it? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try this :

> (((0[1-9])|(1[0-2])):([0-5])([0-9])\s(A|P)M)

test regex [here](https://regex101.com/r/tO2qX6/1)

try this for case sensitive  AM|PM|am|pm
: `

> (((0[1-9])|(1[0-2])):([0-5])(0|5)\s(A|P|a|p)(M|m))

`

Comment: I mean I need AM and PM Should not be case sensitive

Comment: @A.MO—because it needs to be 01:20 or 01:25 (the last group should be `([0-5][0-9])`. ;-)

Comment: (((0[1-9])|(1[0-2])):([0-5])(0|5)\s(A|P|a|p)(M|m)) :  try this

Comment: Thanks Guys It Worked

Comment: Note that this answer only works if the minutes are a multiple of 5, which may not be immediately obvious in the question.

Comment: this is NOT the right answer as per comment by Robert

Answer (score 9):

Try ,

```
^(1[0-2]|0?[1-9]):[0-5][0-9] (AM|PM)$
```

You may test [here](https://regex101.com/r/zF1yS5/1)

Comment: Works like a charm <3

Comment: Remove `?` after `0` to require leading zero in hour.

Comment: The `^` at the beginning is very important because it prevents `17:30 PM` from getting mistaken as `7:30 PM` if the user inputs 24 hour time format by mistake.

Comment: /^(1[0-2]|[1-9]):[0-5][0-9] (AM|PM)$/

I just edit it a little bit and its working perfect in my case.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: proper regex is (1[0-2]|0?[0-9]):[0-5][0-9] (AM|PM) , why you use [1-9] group.. you have to use [0-9] Your answer is 100% ChatGpt response

Comment: @roma2341 I have given this answer in early 2016 :D where ChatGPT was a yet to be in the world

Answer (score 2):

This will work for both pm/am and PM/AM and prefixed with or without 0(Zero)

```
/^(0?[1-9]|1[012])(:[0-5]\d) [APap][mM]$/
```

Answer (score 1):

This is correct after all tests for 12-Hrs clock format,

/(((0[1-9])|(1[0-2])):([0-5][0-9]) ?([AaPp][Mm]))/